# How to show div on the specific value for input slider

Tags: input, rangeslider

I am working on range slide donut chart and want to show div once this input slider hit a specific value.

```
$(function() {
$(".range").on('click', function() {
if ($("input").val() == 70 ) {

document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'inline';
}
else {
document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none';
}
});
})
```

[Entire code in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/talvinder400/bm5vhcLe/)

Comment: I'm quite sure you saw this `Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.` And decided to add your link so that it's not a link instead. Please add (the relevant part of) your code here as it suggests.

Comment: $(function() {
$(".range").on('click', function() {
if ($("input").val() == 70 ) {

document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'inline';
}
else {
document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none';
}
});
})

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply here is the code that I need your support actually with the help of Jquery i want that when input slider hit 70 that Content div data will appear on the screen, which is actually hidden by css.